# Laravel multiple where queries not working

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, eloquent, where-clause

I have the following query that seems to go wrong on the second where (search_price < rrp_price)

```
$query = Product::where('product_name', '!=', 'product_name');

$likes = DB::table('likes')->selectRaw('product_id, COUNT(*) as count')
                  ->groupBy('product_id')
                  ->orderBy('count', 'desc')
                  ->get();
foreach($likes as $like){
   if($like == $likes[0]){
      $query->where('aw_product_id', $like->product_id');
   }
   else{
      $query->orWhere('aw_product_id', $like->product_id');
   }
}
$query->whereRaw('search_price != rrp_price');
$products = $query->get();
```

So, if i take out the 'search_price < rrp_price' where i get all products filtered by those product ids with no price filtering, but when i leave the 'search_price < rrp_price' filter in, nothing seems to happen (search_price and rrp_price are always the same).

Am i doing anything obvoiously wrong with my where statements?

Comment: Where is search_price < rrp_price'

Comment: search_price < rrp_price is the last line.
They are properties in the table.

Comment: Ah sorry, it should be !=

I've been playing around with != and < , but the issue remains on both so doesn't seem dependant on that

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `<>` instead of `!=` ? Maybe it'll work

Comment: It's the "not equal" operator for SQL.

Comment: Ah thanks, doesn't make any difference. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

There is error in your query Modified query is as below :

```
foreach($likes as $like){
   if($like == $likes[0]){
      $query->where('aw_product_id', $like->product_id);
   }
   else{
      $query->Where('aw_product_id', $like->product_id);
   }
}
```

Comment: That makes it a 'and where', rather than a 'or where', right?
That part of the query works, it's the price filter that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try any other where syntax? something like this:

```
->where('table.search_price', '<>', DB::raw('table.rrp_price'))
```

Or maybe (Laravel 5+):

```
->whereColumn('table.search_price','<>','table.rrp_price')
```

Comment: They don't seem to work either. It's probably worth mentioning that i'm casting the value to a string (as some of the prices include a GBP suffix) and then stripping them of any currency values, and converting to a float.

Also, if i run the query in the original question without the product id filter, the price filter works. Odd

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it was because the values were strings. Even though I was casting 'search_price' and 'rrp_price' to be floats, the actual laravel query seemed to be comparing string values in the database.

I modified the values in the database to be floats (for now) and now the query works.